# Can I run multiple windows at the same time when using selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I want to open several more windows when starting selenium, and each window can run independently:

```py
from lxml import etree
import re
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By  # 选择器
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys  # 按键
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait  # 等待页面加载完毕，寻找某些元素
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC  # 等待指定标签加载完毕
import time
import pymysql
import random
import threading
import string
from requests_html import HTMLSession
# 构造请求对象
session = HTMLSession()


class A3dModelFile(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.url = 'https://clara.io/signup'
        self.options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        self.options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-automation'])
        self.browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=self.options)
        time.sleep(1)
        self.browser.get(self.url)

    def other_window(self):
        self.browser.execute_script("window.open('https://clara.io/signup')")
        time.sleep(1)
        self.login()
        self.get_label()

    def main_window(self):
        self.login()
        self.get_label()

    def login(self):
        pass

    def get_label(self):
        pass

    def run(self):
        threads = []  # 定义线程池
        t1 = threading.Thread(target=a.main_window)
        threads.append(t1)  # 将函数接入线程池
        index = 2
        while True:
            t2 = threading.Thread(target=a.other_window)
            index += 1
            threads.append(t2)
            if index == 3:
                return threads


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = A3dModelFile()
    threads = a.run()
    for t in threads:
        t.start()
```

I've tried many times, but I can only run one window independently.

I want every window to run the same function method, but only the main window can run.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use multiple windows in Selenium:

1. `driver.get(2nd website)` (opens a new window)
2. presses key to switch tabs like ctrl + 1 for firefox
3. `driver.quit()` (closes only that tab but doesn't close the whole browser)

Comment: If you use driver get (), the second website will overwrite the first website. What I want is to use the same website to open a main window, then open multiple sub windows, and then each window executes the same function method